# Is amp-next-page a way to preload other pages in users cache?

Tags: amp-html

Or is it limited to adding to the current page like i can understand in this statement ?

> Given a list of pages, amp-next-page tries to load them after the
>   current document, providing an infinite-scroll type experience.

from this page https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-next-page

Answer (score 1):

amp-next-page will load the next page into the current document (so that it's visible). As a side-effect it will also land in the user's cache, but that's probably not what you had it mind. If you're interested in pre-caching a page for faster subsequent navigation, you'd need to do this using a service worker installed via amp-install-serviceworker.